# How to use external Java Script file for AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My ajax is working with inner java script. I want to make it as external `JS` file. which is not working as follows.

html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>      
</head> 
<body>
    <div>
        <input name="submit1" id="submit1" type="button" value="Load">
    </div>
    <div id="receive">           
    </div>
</body>
```

`JS` file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit1').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "data1.php",
        dataType: "JSON",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(retdata){
            $("#receive").html(retdata.name);
        }
    });
}); });
```

PHP file
`data1.php` returns `echo(json_encode($student_data));`//works fine with inner JS

Comment: Does it work if you embed it in <body> instead of <head>?

Comment: Just checking: you have `src="scripts.js"` -- should it be `src="js/scripts.js"` ?

Comment: Check your developer console - is your `scripts.js` file being fetched correctly?

Comment: @ElGavilan: It's working inside body, @gibberish: I  put 'JS' file on same `dir`, @NickZuber: when i put same code inside head with script tags, its working as i want.

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: @Manikiran no any errors even when i used ajax error : function

Comment: Okay, I am not sure what your error is so here are few possible corrections (which may or may not help). 1. Use `jQuery` instead of `$` for removing jquery conflicts. 2. Use `$('body').on('click','#submit1',function(){`  instead of `$('#submit1').click(function(){` for correcting dynamic content errors.

Comment: (1) Are you absolutely certain the `<script>` code in head is identical, including capitalization, to the external .js file code? (2) Try adding reference to external script as last item in body, instead of in head or top of body. (3) Try wrapping your code in: `setTimeout(function(){ //your js code here },5000);` -- this tests whether your document.ready is doing its job. `Manikiran`'s suggestions (above) are important - esp. the use of `.on()`